# PHP- How to sum value using foreach with condition?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have an array in array like this:

```
$myArr = [0=>['id1'=>'01','id2'=>'00','val'=>0],
          1=>['id1'=>'01','id2'=>'01','val'=>100],
          2=>['id1'=>'01','id2'=>'02','val'=>200],
          3=>['id1'=>'02','id2'=>'00','val'=>250],
          4=>['id1'=>'02','id2'=>'01','val'=>0],
          5=>['id1'=>'02','id2'=>'02','val'=>0],
         ...]
```

it's an array in array. When `id2` value is `'00'` it indicates the array is a head.
It's mean the array index `0` is a head of array index `1` and `2` and so on.

I want to create a new array in **PHP** using `foreach` with a result of each head  `val` is sum of their child `val`. **BUT** if they already have their own `val` then ignored it.

this is an result that I want:

```
    $myArr = [0=>['id1'=>'01','id2'=>'00','val'=>300],
              1=>['id1'=>'01','id2'=>'01','val'=>100],
              2=>['id1'=>'01','id2'=>'02','val'=>200],
              3=>['id1'=>'02','id2'=>'00','val'=>250],
              4=>['id1'=>'02','id2'=>'01','val'=>0],
              5=>['id1'=>'02','id2'=>'02','val'=>0],
              ...]
```

Comment: where's the foreach code?

Comment: @Kevin that's what I asking for.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, you are expected to make some effort and people will help fix your  problems.

Comment: Sorry, I am new here @NigelRen , I'll be more specific next time.

Answer (score 1):

There are various approaches for data processing of this kind. There is no clear right or wrong. Often it pays out to invest into making your task easier instead of solving it, so reducing the complexity of the input data in this case.

If that is not possible here is one possible approach:

```
<?php
$data = [
  ['id1'=>'01','id2'=>'00','val'=>0],
  ['id1'=>'01','id2'=>'01','val'=>100],
  ['id1'=>'01','id2'=>'02','val'=>200],
  ['id1'=>'02','id2'=>'00','val'=>250],
  ['id1'=>'02','id2'=>'01','val'=>0],
  ['id1'=>'02','id2'=>'02','val'=>0],
  ['id1'=>'03','id2'=>'00','val'=>200],
  ['id1'=>'03','id2'=>'01','val'=>20],
  ['id1'=>'03','id2'=>'02','val'=>20]
];

$i = 0; 
$j = 0;
while ($i < count($data)) {

  // sum up values of sequence
  $sum = 0;
  while (++$j < count($data) && $data[$j]['id1'] == $data[$i]['id1']) {
    $sum += $data[$j]['val'];
  }

  // replace value of sequence header if sum is not 0
  if ($sum > 0) {
    $data[$i]['val'] = $sum;
  }
  
  // jump to next sequence
  $i = $j;
}

print_r($data);
```

The obvious output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id1] => 01
            [id2] => 00
            [val] => 300
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id1] => 01
            [id2] => 01
            [val] => 100
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id1] => 01
            [id2] => 02
            [val] => 200
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id1] => 02
            [id2] => 00
            [val] => 250
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id1] => 02
            [id2] => 01
            [val] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id1] => 02
            [id2] => 02
            [val] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id1] => 03
            [id2] => 00
            [val] => 40
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id1] => 03
            [id2] => 01
            [val] => 20
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id1] => 03
            [id2] => 02
            [val] => 20
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can foreach over that, and remember the top level index for the last id2==00 record you encounter. For all other records, you add up the values, until you come accross the next id2==00 record. Then you need to write the sum into the record with the key you previously remembered, remember the new key, and reset your sum variable. And then at the end/after the loop, when there will be no next id2==00 record, you will have to write the last sum into the last remembered index again. Or …

… you simply use a for loop, to go through the data in *reverse* order. Then you can just sum up the values, and when you come across an id2==00 record, you just write the current sum into there, reset your sum, and continue. That’s a bit easier, you don’t have to remember any indexes, and you don’t have to handle the last case seperately either.

```
$data = [
  ['id1'=>'01','id2'=>'00','val'=>0],
  ['id1'=>'01','id2'=>'01','val'=>100],
  ['id1'=>'01','id2'=>'02','val'=>200],
  ['id1'=>'02','id2'=>'00','val'=>250],
  ['id1'=>'02','id2'=>'01','val'=>0],
  ['id1'=>'02','id2'=>'02','val'=>0],
  ['id1'=>'03','id2'=>'00','val'=>200],
  ['id1'=>'03','id2'=>'01','val'=>20],
  ['id1'=>'03','id2'=>'02','val'=>20]
];

for($sum = 0, $i = count($data)-1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
  if($data[$i]['id2'] == '00') {
    if($data[$i]['val'] == 0) { // set sum only if there wasn’t a value already
      $data[$i]['val'] = $sum;
    }
    $sum = 0;
  }
  else {
    $sum += $data[$i]['val'];
  }
}

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: This is what actually I looking for. thank you so much.